# Joint Probability Function

Tags: probability, functions, problem-solving

Two hats are drawn randomly w/o replacement from box containing $8$ black, $4$ red, and $2$ yellow hats. If $X$ denotes the number of black hats drawn and $Y$ the number of red hats drawn. What is the joint probability function $f(x,y)$ of $X$ and $Y$? So I have to give the values of $X$ and $Y$ and their probabilities.

Here's my thoughts:
$$\begin{align}
X & = {{8 \choose x}{6 \choose  2-x}}\bigg/{{14 \choose  2}}
\\[1ex]
Y & = {{4 \choose x}{10 \choose 2-x}}\bigg/{{14 \choose 2}}
\end{align}$$

Is that the values of $X$ and $Y$? Not sure what the exactly the proper answer is for the question. Thanks in advance.

Comment: See [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to learn about mathjaxs yntax.

Comment: The values regarding X and Y look right to me, and it seems you already know how to continue from there.

Comment: @Studentmath actually, those are the probabilities of X and Y.

Comment: @Graham that's what I meant, and I guess that's what the OP meant. But it is indeed better to word such things more carefully.

Comment: @user188034: Tip: instead of `(a \text{ choose } b)` use `{a \choose b}` to give ${a\choose b}$

Comment: Have a look: http://www.wyzant.com/resources/lessons/math/statistics_and_probability/probability_distributions/joint_probability_distributions

Answer (score 0):

$\checkmark$ so far. What you have are actually the probability measures of $X$ and $Y$ at certain integer values.

For $X$: you are selecting $x\in\{0,1,2\}$ of 8 black hats out of all the ways to select 2 hats from 14.  Likewise for $Y$: you are selecting $y\in\{0,1,2\}$ of 4 red hats out of the same probability space.

$$\begin{align}
f_X(x)=\mathsf P(X=x) & = {{8 \choose x}{6 \choose  2-x}}\bigg/{{14 \choose  2}} & \text{if } x\in \{0,1,2\}
\\[1ex]
f_Y(y)=\mathsf P(Y=y) & = {{4 \choose y}{10 \choose 2-y}}\bigg/{{14 \choose 2}} & \text{if } y\in \{0,1,2\}
\end{align}$$

However you require the joint probability measure. $f(x,y)=\mathsf P(X=x, Y=y)$  (Note: these are *not* independent random variables, so you cannot use the product rule.)

You need to count ways to select both $x\in\{0,1,2\}$ of 8 black hats AND $y\in\{0,1,2\}$ of 4 red hats out of the same probability space.  There is an additional constraint that $x+y\leq 2$.

$$\begin{align}
f(x,y)=\mathsf P(X=x,Y=y) & = \boxed{?} &  \text{if } x\in \{0,1,2\}, y\in\{0\ldots 2-x\}
\end{align}$$

Can you fill in the box now?